# UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, swift, gesture, uipangesturerecognizer

I'm trying to implement screen edge pan gesture for my view controller. But the problem is, if trying to add edge pan gesture for two edges (UIRectEdge.left, UIRectEdge.right) as

```
let screenEdgePanGesture = UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: #selector(self.didPanningScreen))
screenEdgePanGesture.edges = [.right, .left]
screenEdgePanGesture.delegate = self
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(screenEdgePanGesture)
```

the selector method not calling. But the edge pan gesture is working for one edge i.e.,

```
let screenEdgePanGesture = UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: #selector(self.didPanningScreen))
screenEdgePanGesture.edges = .right
screenEdgePanGesture.delegate = self
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(screenEdgePanGesture)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you are right, `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer` `edges` is accept/working only with one value, So you need to create two different functions for left and right edge panning.

**Swift 4**

```
let screenEdgePanGestureRight = UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: #selector(self.didPanningScreenRight(_:)))
screenEdgePanGestureRight.edges = .right
screenEdgePanGestureRight.delegate = self
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(screenEdgePanGestureRight)

let screenEdgePanGestureLeft = UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: #selector(self.didPanningScreenLeft(_:)))
screenEdgePanGestureLeft.edges = .left
screenEdgePanGestureLeft.delegate = self
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(screenEdgePanGestureLeft)

@objc func didPanningScreenRight(_ recognizer: UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer)  {
    print("Right edge penning")
}

@objc func didPanningScreenLeft(_ recognizer: UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer)  {
    print("Left edge penning")
}
```

Comment: @AtulParmar - do you have any experience adding the screen edge pan gesture alongside note swipe actions?